# Why doesn't the console output the right answer?

Tags: c++, math

I have 2 numbers, n = 1000000000000, and j = 1. When I write

```
 cout << n / j << endl;
```

The console outputs the right answer, 1000000000000.
However, when I do :

```
int d = n / j;
cout << d << endl;
```

The console outputs 3567587328.
Can someone please explain why this happens and what should I do?

Comment: use bigger data types

Comment: Can you show the actual code you are using?  `n = 1000000000000` should at least issue a warning.

Comment: Perhaps your `n` and/or `j` variables are not of type `int` ?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The value you are using is greater than the maximum value that an integer variable can store.

If you need to perform arithmetic operation with such big numbers then you will have to use special classes that handle such numbers. Perhaps your implementation of C++ supports the `long long` data type?

Comment: "Perhaps your implementation of C++ supports the long long data type?". It's 2016

Comment: @bolov And people are still being taught on turbo C++.

Answer (score 0):

The max `int` you can have is 2,147,483,647 which is way smaller that 10^12 that you have there, so you have an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Instead of an `int` you could use `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using long.

```
long long d = n / j;
cout << d << endl;
```

Comment: `long` and `int` are the same size on most modern computers.  If you want to recommend a 64 bit type you should use `long long`.

Comment: Thank you! Corrected answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver A large number of 64 bit platforms provides  64 bit long and 32 bit int (e.g. 64 bit linux and OSX) - But yes - use a long long